# If $\{a,b,c\}\subset[1,2]$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+a+b^2}\leq\frac{3}{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $\{a,b,c\}\subset[1,2]$. Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{1+a+b^2}+\frac{1}{1+b+c^2}+\frac{1}{1+c+a^2}\leq\frac{3}{a+b+c}$$
The equality occurs also for $a=b=1$ and $c=2$.

I have a proof of this inequality, but my proof is very ugly.

The convexity does not help here. At least, I don't see, how we can use it.

I'am looking for a nice proof, which we can  realize  during a competition.